# Is it possible to declare module inputs at compile time in verilog?

Tags: verilog

For instance, I have the following generate block:

```
localparam N = 4
localparam P = 16
genvar i;
generate 
    for(i=0;i<P;i=i+1)
        begin: dmnGen
        localparam [N-1:0]r = func_r(i);   
        and dmn(OUT[i], S[3][r[3]], S[2][r[2]], S[1][r[1]], S[0][r[0]], EN);
    end
endgenerate
```

I would like to add `S[x][r[x]]` inputs to the and gate based on parameter N. Is it possible to programmatically add inputs at compile time?

Comment: no, it is not possible in verilog. But you can always create a script which will generate verilog for you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the number of port connections based on a parameter. But you can either generate a set of cascading `and` gates, you better yet, use a reduction & operator.

```
localparam N = 4
localparam P = 16

genvar i,j;
  for(i=0;i<P;i=i+1) begin: dmnGen
    localparam [N-1:0]r = func_r(i);
    wire [N-1:0] p;
    assign OUT[i] = &p;
    for(j=0;j<N;j=j+1)
     assign p[j] = S[j][r[j]];
  end
endgenerate
```